# How to find and replace a string in python with a large data set

Tags: python, delimiter, large-files

I am trying to change the delimiter of a large file that is about 4GB. The delimiter is currently "#|#" and I want the delimiter to be "|".

I tried to do a replace and find, but due to the large file my computer does not have enough memory to finish the code. I was wondering if there is a way to read the files line by line instead to save memory.

```
text = open("C:\\test.txt", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace("#|#", "|")
x = open("C:\\test.txt","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

This is what the file currently looks like:

FIELD #|# FIELD #|# FIELD #|#

and I want it to look like

FIELD | FIELD | FIELD |

Comment: The [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html) module lets you iterate files (similar to `open`) and edit them in-place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can write line-by-line.
In fact in general, file handling is more practical in the more idiomatic way of using the file object as a context manager and an iterator of lines:

```
import shutil

with open("C:\\test.txt", "r") as long_file, \
     open("C:\\test_replaced.tmp", "w") as replacement:
    for line in long_file:
        replacement.write(line.replace("#|#", "|"))

shutil.move("C:\\test_replaced.tmp", "C:\\test.txt")
```

This works as long as you can write the temporary file to disk without causing trouble.
I do not have a good, succinct solution using the standard library for doing an in-place change to the file, but this should already be much faster and more memory efficient than iterating over the same file twice and reading the whole content into memory.

Comment: This is significantly faster and does not use up all my memory. Thank you!!

Comment: You should also try the solution of @b_c, using fileinput. I've never heard of this being part of the standard library, but it is, looks cool and if it works, is much better than my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead of reading the entire file to memory:

```
text = open("C:\\test.txt", "r")
text = ''.join((i for i in text)).replace("#|#", "|")
x = open("C:\\test.txt","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

`(i for i in text)` syntax allows lazy generation of lines as opposed to `[i for i in text]` when you load all lines to memory

Comment: This generator is ineffectual, since the join method will have to iterate through it completely to construct the resulting string. OPs list is also mutable, hence is passed by reference, so there is no benefit during argument passing either.

Comment: Agree. So, no need to use list comprehension but rather loop over generated lines modify them,  and write them to the some file.

Comment: But for that, you either need a temporary file, or have the same file open for both reading and writing, and seek so the two pointers don't slip away from each other. This is not so easy to do with line-based I/O operations.
I also tested your current generator-based solution and it seems to be just as slow as OPs list-based one.

Comment: i agree, you answer is better